# jquery : animate list scrollLeft/scrollRight on mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouseevent

I have the following code to scroll left/right when user use mouse wheel. Event is well binded because i go to the JS code when the user try to scroll, but the code has never effect.

```
<div id="contact_list">
    <ul id="contact_list_ul">
        <li>img1</li>
        <li>img2</li>
        <li>img3</li>
        <li>img4</li>
        <li>img5</li>
        <li>img6</li>
        <li>img7</li>
        <li>img8</li>
        <li>img9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS : (I use overflow-x because i want to hide the scrollbar)

```
#contact_list ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

JS code to scroll right/left :

```
$("#contact_list_ul").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
   var o = '';
   if (deltaY > 0){
     $("#contact_list_ul").animate({scrollRight : '-=200'}, 'slow');
   } else if (deltaY < 0) {
     $("#contact_list_ul").animate({scrollRight :'+=200'}, 'slow');
   }
});
```

Comment: Have you added the mousewheel library?

Comment: then try with `if(event.deltaY < 0)` or else.

Comment: @Jai I tried but there is no changes. Even in chrome debugguer, when i put the following line in debug `$("#contact_list_ul").animate({scrollRight : '-=200'}, 'slow');` the scroll is not done. Is there a mistake ?

Comment: just posted an answer take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is no method in jquery named `scrollRight` so i think that should be `scrollLeft`.

Try this:

```js
    $("#contact_list_ul").mousewheel(function(event) {
       var o = '';
       if (event.deltaY > 0){
         $("#contact_list_ul").animate({scrollLeft : '-=200'}, 'slow');
       } else if (event.deltaY < 0) {
         $("#contact_list_ul").animate({scrollLeft :'+=200'}, 'slow');
       }
    });
```

```css
    #contact_list ul {
       list-style-type: none;
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow-x: hidden;
      width:400px;
      border:solid 1px red;
    }
#contact_list ul li{
width:200px; display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <div id="contact_list">
     <ul id="contact_list_ul">
            <li>img1</li>
            <li>img2</li>
            <li>img3</li>
            <li>img4</li>
            <li>img5</li>
            <li>img6</li>
            <li>img7</li>
            <li>img8</li>
            <li>img9</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```